# Output 2 Column / 2 Row Table - PHP / MySQL - For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Right now, I am attempting to have a `For` loop create a table displaying the different Herds (Groups) in the Database.

As of now, my code looks like this:

```
echo '<table>';
for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++) {  
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) 
   $name = $row['name']; 
   $avatar = $row['avatar']; 
   $link = $row['link'];

   echo '<tr>'; 
   echo '<td>'.$avatar.'</td>'; 
   echo '<td><a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a></td>'; 
   echo '</tr>'; 
}
echo '</table>';
```

Which, displays this:

> [Avatar] [Name]
>  [Avatar] [Name]
>  [Avatar] [Name]

How would I be able to produce this (all being separate records):

> [Avatar] [Name]  [Avatar] [Name] 
>  [Avatar] [Name]  [Avatar]
>   [Name] 
>  [Avatar] [Name]  [Avatar] [Name]

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, If I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: The second table, is that 2 tables side by side, or ? What's your end goal?

Comment: @odannyc - I guess it would be considered a 4 column table. I'm trying to have it generate depending on the amount of names.

Comment: Right now, it displays the table straight up and down. I'm trying to get it side by side, so to speak.

Comment: Determine the number of records you have in the query. Determine how many rows you would like to see in the table. Divide the two numbers and round the result up and you get the number of times you need to repeat the name and avatar columns. Then have 2 loops, the outer for rows, the inner for columns to generate the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
    $numrows = 10;
    $col = 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++) {
    $name = "name";
    $avatar = "avatar";
    $link = "localhost";
        if($i % $col == 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>'.$avatar.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="'.$link.'">'.$name.'</a></td>';
    }
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```